# Creating a custom rebrandly link using a wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to create a rebrandly short link using a WordPress shortcode. Here's what I have so far:

```
add_shortcode( 'shortlink', 'rebrandly_shortcode');
function rebrandly_shortcode( $content = null ) {
    
$domain_data["fullName"] = "rebrand.ly";
$post_data["destination"] = $content;
$post_data["domain"] = $domain_data;
$ch = curl_init("https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "apikey: 67c55f8b4e5d4f079cfc866b2b80b4f5",
  "Content-Type: application/json"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($result, true);

return "Short URL is: " . $response["shortUrl"];
    
}
```

Following the directions for PHP here - https://developers.rebrandly.com/docs

The shortcode I'm testing is `[shortlink]https://example.com[/shortlink]` but its not working.

When I change the part:
`$post_data["destination"] = $content;`
to
`$post_data["destination"] = "http://example.com";`
it works.

I must be putting in the shortcode content wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an argument in your [shortcode function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). The the parameter list for all shortcode functions is `($attributes, $content=null)`. This means that first parameter passed in by Wordpress is going to be the attributes (whether you have any or not), and the content between the shortcode tags is *second*.

Your code is trying to use the first parameter as `$content`, but as WP is actually passing in attributes first, this is empty in your case.

You just need to change your function to match the defined parameter list to include both arguments (even if you don't have any attributes), i.e.:

```
// $attributes argument first, $content second
function rebrandly_shortcode( $attributes, $content = null ) {    
    
    // do your stuff here

}
```

---

**FYI**

**Shortcode attributes** are information you can add to the shortcode to be used in the function, for example a class, some text to include, or anything else.

If we take your code as an example, you could pass in different shortlink domains on different pages as follows (obviously this isn't a *practical* example, but it shows how it works!)

```
[shortlink domain="rebrand.ly"]
```

Then the function can extract the attributes to be used as follows:

```
function rebrandly_shortcode( $attributes, $content = null ) {
    // extract the apikey attribute into a variable called $domain
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'domain' => '' // you could also give it a default value here instead of ''
    ), $attributes ) );

    // use your domain parameter
    $domain_data["fullName"] = $domain;

   // do the rest of your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you @fluffykitten. I actually don't have any attributes needed for this, just the content inside the shortcode. Is it possible to use the $content inside the function like you would with attributes?

Comment: Even if you're not using attributes, the definition for shortcode functions specifies that `$attributes` is the first parameter so you need to include it anyway - you just don't have to use it in your function. The way you are using `$content` in your function is fine - the only problem is that your function isn't getting it because it's not in the correct place in the parameter list. If you change your function argument list to what I have in the first example above, it should work!

Comment: @CharlieWedel I've updated my answer to explain it further... let me know if that & my comment above helps!